# Can an extension be a has-a relation?

Tags: java, oop

As far as I know an Is-a relation is where your class extends another class, i.e., `A` extends `B` therefore `A` is a `B`.

And a has-a relation is when a class implements an interface so `A` has an algoritm.

My question: *is there ever a situation where an is-a is also a has-a?*

or where implementing an interface can become a is-a relation?

let me rephase that:

*can a class have an is-a relationship if it implements an interface?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> And a has-a relation is when a class implements an interface so A has
>   a Aalgoritm.

This statement is wrong. if you implement an interface its still a Is-A relationship.

Has-A relationship (composition) is something like this:

```
Class ABC {
private XYZ z;
}
```

ABC has-a XYZ.

Comment: So both extends and implements are is-a relations?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of `has a` relationship is expressed with composition, not interface-implementation.

personally, I think `is-a` and `has-a` could happen at same time:

```
class Foo{
 Bar bar;
}

Foo is a(n) Object.
Foo has a(n) Object. (Bar is Object too.)
```

Answer (score 0):

has-a relation has nothing to do with an interface - it is rather like A has some member of type B or A encapsulates B.

Regarding your question, consider the following:

```
interface IFSA {
     void foo();
 }

 class A implements IFSA { 
     void foo(){}
 }

 class B extends A {}
```

A is-a B and it implements an interface IFSA, so the answer is yes.